# CI build not creating _PublishedWebsite folder in the drop folder (TFS 2010)

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I have created a MVC 5 application  in VS 2013 and the csproj file contains :

```
 <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
```

However on checking-in I am not able to view _PublishedWebsite folder in the drop folder.

I have also tried adding a .pubxml file.

and added

/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile = Profile_Name

in the MSBuild arguments

Any input on this will be helpful.

Comment: Are you building a solution file or a csproj file?

Comment: @Daniel Mann I am building the solution file

Comment: Try removing all of the p/ options and building.

Comment: @MrHinsh I tried removing /p options and it didn't work. So tried adding them too

Comment: Is visual studio installed on your build server?

Comment: @MrHinsh Yes, VS 2013 is installed in the build machine

Comment: @MrHinsh Also I see the entry in the log file as:

Comment: Validating PublishProfile(xxxGUI) settings.
       ValidateGlobalPackageSetting:
         $(PackageAsSingleFile) is True
         $(PackageFileName) is bin\_PublishedWebsites\<Solutionname>_Package\<Solution name>.zip. Validating...
       CollectFilesFromIntermediateAssembly:

Comment: Finally the issue was resolved by adding the parameter  /p:OutDir = <pointing to bin folder>.